# Default values for \xxxdisplayskip

Tags: spacing, equations

I've changed the values for the `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, but I want to set them back to normal after a specific equation. What are the standard values?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\the\abovedisplayskip{} and \the\belowdisplayskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @newbie Glad to hear that. If this answers your question, please accept it as such in order to close this topic. Accepting and upvoting are the ways to say thank you here. If this answer is not complete for you, please edit your question in order to clarify what you need.

Comment: I wanted to accept the answer, but when I click on the tick, I get a message "You can accept an answer in ... minutes". As soon as this time expires, I will do it. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Rather than resetting the value you might use the grouping feature of TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text that wraps over two lines, let's hope
it's long enough, but, just in case, let's add some
more nonsense
\begingroup\abovedisplayskip=30pt \belowdisplayskip=30pt
\[
1+1=2
\]
\endgroup
Some text that wraps over two lines, let's hope
it's long enough, but, just in case, let's add some
more nonsense
\[
1+1=2
\]
Some text that wraps over two lines, let's hope
it's long enough, but, just in case, let's add some
more nonsense

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. In fact, this method is far better. I've upvoted it, but I accepted the other answer, because of the formulation of my question.

Comment: @egreg your last sentence is missing a "need to", I believe. If not, I do not really understand. I just want to inform you in case you miss-typed. I will delete this in some time.

Comment: @newbie Well, there are no “standard values”. If you change some details in your document, such as the default point size, also the values of those parameters will change; if you rely on grouping, you don't need to know what the initial values are.