# \belowdisplayskip and \abovedisplayskip weird behaviour

Tags: equations, belowdisplayskip

I needed QED symbol to be placed properly in proof environment in cases when the last sentence is an equation since in such cases the white space looks too large.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267485/292801) suggests nice options \belowdisplayskip and \abovedisplayskip, which I'm using now, but then I discovered some anomalies (see below). Any tips how to fix it?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Case 1: default:
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 2: \verb|\abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt|:
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 3: \verb|\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip|:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 4:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\textbf{Remark}. Cases 3 and 4 have \textit{the same option} (\verb|\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip|), but QED position is lower in Case 4. It looks like \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| are completely ignored when the length of the text "Case 4" is too short.
\begin{proof}
Case 5: a longer text here and this becomes the same case as Case 3.
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

But the story doesn't end here; we have another anomaly when we use more than one equation inside proof environment.

\begin{proof}
Case 6: options \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| work for the first equation only (and the length of this text doesn't matter).
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
tx
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

In case 6 the options \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| for the second equation don't work unless it's a longer text than "tx" (Case 7):

\begin{proof}
Case 7: options \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| work for the first equation only (and the length of this text doesn't matter).
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
txt
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

But if the last equation is too short then it stops working:

\begin{proof}
Case 8:
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
Second equation is short:
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 9:
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
But with long enough text here it starts working again:
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\qedhere` is not an option?

Comment: @mickep Thanks, I might use `\qedhere` in some cases, but I'm using my own proof-like environment (with a bunch of styles), so I need to know what's exactly wrong with the proof environment before I decide to create a completely new environment (I'm trying to avoid that).

Comment: case 4 will be using ``\abovedisplashortskip`  and `\belowdisplayshortskip`

Comment: why are you setting the abovedisp;ayskip, don't you just want to adjust the belowskip the qed marker?

Comment: the displayskips are almost always a global setting, I've hardly ever seen them tweaksed on a per-equation basis. (but you could adjust them as part of a qed macro)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle `\belowdisplayshortskip` worked, good to know. It's not just about QED symbol, I needed to control space after equations in some other instances too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `\belowdisplayshortskip`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Case 1: default:
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 2: \verb|\abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt|:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 3: \verb|\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip|:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 4:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\textbf{Remark}. Cases 3 and 4 have \textit{the same option} (\verb|\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip|), but QED position is lower in Case 4. It looks like \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| are completely ignored when the length of the text "Case 4" is too short.
\begin{proof}
Case 5: a longer text here and this becomes the same case as Case 3.
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

But the story doesn't end here; we have another anomaly when we use more than one equation inside proof environment.

\begin{proof}
Case 6: options \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| work for the first equation only (and the length of this text doesn't matter).
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
tx
\begingroup \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

In case 6 the options \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| for the second equation don't work unless it's a longer text than "tx" (Case 7):

\begin{proof}
Case 7: options \verb|\belowdisplayskip| and \verb|\abovedisplayskip| work for the first equation only (and the length of this text doesn't matter).
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
txt
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

But if the last equation is too short then it stops working:

\begin{proof}
Case 8:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
Second equation is short:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Case 9:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = a_7 = a_9 = a_{10} = a_{11} = a_{12} = a_{13}\]
\endgroup
But with long enough text here it starts working again:
\begingroup \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\[a_1 = a_2\]
\endgroup
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]